# h1 with 3 different text align properties

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to have one h1 tag that is broken up into 3 different lines using `<br>` and have different `text-align` properties.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
}

h1 #first {
  text-align: left;
}

h1 #second {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 #third {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h1><span id="first">First</span><br><span id="second">Middle</span><br><span id="third">Last</span></h1>
```

Using absolutes would work but I am wondering if there is an more efficient way.

Comment: `text-align` only works on block-level elements, so _not_ `<span>`s.

Answer (score 2):

Use flex properties. Very simple, clean and efficient.

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#first {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

#second {
  align-self: center;
}

#third {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span id="first">First</span>
  <span id="second">Middle</span>
  <span id="third">Last</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS.

```
h1 span{
    display:block;
}
```

span is inline element. so text-align is not working bacause it's not taking full width of container.

or add the ids to h1 tag and remove from span. then it will be working fine